# Angular 7 :Apply style sheet to input field on change of value i.e when Entered date is less than current date

Tags: html, css, angular

I am very new to HTML and CSS.
 I had encountered a production issue that the field should not allow a user to save, when the entered date is less than the current date. I can make it work for simple Html input field but in application it is tricky

I have written a function in component typescript file which will store messages when the entered date is less than the current date and display the message

```
<msw-datetime-picker  formControlName="dueDate" [pickerType]="'calendar'" (valueChange)="checkDueDate($event, i)"></msw-datetime-picker>
                  <msw-validation-errors [hidden]="certificateControls.controls[i].controls.dueDate.dirty"
                    [errors]="certificateControls.controls[i].controls.dueDate.errors"  errorPrefix="Expiry Date">
                  </msw-validation-errors>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="errorMsg && errorMsg[i] && errorMsg[i].showWarning">
                    {{errorMsg[i].warningMessage}}
                  </ng-container>
```

component.ts

```
checkDueDate(enteredDate)
    {
         if(enteredDate<=currentDate)
        {
           //get the input field
           const expiryDate = this.otherInfoForm['controls']['panShipCertificates']['controls'][i] 
             ['controls']['dueDate'];
           expiryDate.setValidators([Validators.required]);  
           expiryDate.markAsDirty();
           //this.otherDetail.burningLng.setErrors({'required': true});
           **this.errorMsg[i]** = { showWarning: true, warningMessage: "Date is Expired" }

         }
    }
```

I suppose to apply below CSS when **this.errorMsg[i]** contains the message

```
msw-datetime-picker.ng-dirty.ng-invalid input.form-control {
        border: 1px solid #FFABAB !important;
        display: block;
    }
```

UI Experts, Please help what is the best way to apply CSS in this case

- 1.is it possible to apply CSS from component.ts file i.e within the checkDueDate() function? or

  2. Apply CSS in the Template file when the ng-container contains the message?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First, try to minimize your css classes like below:
Your code:

```
msw-datetime-picker.ng-dirty.ng-invalid input.form-control {
    border: 1px solid #FFABAB !important;
    display: block;
}
```

Improvement:

```
.example-class {
    border: 1px solid #FFABAB !important;
    display: block;
}
```

Now, you can use ngClass with condition here for this scenario.

In your code:

```
  <div class="date-error" [ngClass]="{'first': errorMsg[i].length > 0 }" *ngIf="errorMsg && errorMsg[i] && errorMsg[i].showWarning">
        {{errorMsg[i].warningMessage}}
  </div>
```

Or, you can use a variable which returns to true if `errorMsg[i].length > 0` returns true and use it in your template.

Comment: do not use ngClass on a <ng-container>, it is used to group nodes not to be applied any class.

Comment: With angular 9 it displays an unhelpful error and make things laggy : ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined